# Can I omit the x parameter in ggplot like plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a line with `ggplot` instead of `plot`. But I found that I have to set the parameter x in aes(), even the x is just the number of points. Is there a way to omit setting the x in ggplot?

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10))
head(df)
        y
1  -0.6264538
2   0.1836433
3  -0.8356286
4   1.5952808
5   0.3295078
6  -0.8204684
7   0.4874291
8   0.7383247
9   0.5757814
10 -0.3053884

# This is OK
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:nrow(df), y=df$y), type="l") + geom_line()

# But this is wrong
ggplot(df, aes(y=df$y), type="l") + geom_line()

# with plot(), it is very easy:
plot(df$y, type="l")
```

Comment: No, some geom's have required aesthetics. **ggplot** wants you to be explicit about the variables. And you should never be using `$` inside of `aes()`, only type the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be acceptable

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10), x=1:10)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
```

or alternatively `ggplot(df, aes(x=1:10, y=y)) + geom_line()`

[image]

I am not really omitting the x parameter, but here's an alternative suggestion.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10))
df$x <- as.numeric(row.names(df))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as doing `x=1:nrow(df)` like OP shows in the question?  I don't really understand what, if they have a working answer, the answer to this question would be :)

Comment: I guess it is, but without the `$`.